# Prestashop - Layered Navigation is Empty

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, layered-navigation

I'm working on a prestashop site and facing some problem with the layered navigation. It appears for the top level categories but when I click on any of the sub categories, it goes to blank. There is nothing to filter on. It should atleast display a Price filter.

And yes I do have products in the category with different prices so a price filter should appear.

In my header.tpl file I have

```
{if isset($left_column_size) && !empty($left_column_size)}
    <div id="left_column" class="column col-xs-12 col-sm-{$left_column_size|intval}">{$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}</div>
{/if}
```

Which hides the left column when I don't have anything in my layered navigation. I want to diagnose why I don't have anything in my layered navigation.

Comment: did you check the block layered is configured to all categories when editing the filters of it?

Comment: Umm...what do you mean "configured to all categories"?

Comment: you need to edit the filter(s) in the blocklayered navigation modules, and select all categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the filter(s) in all categories you have to configure a blocklayered 'template' with all categories of your shop.

I'll post a screenshot to better understating :)

Enter in the module configuration, then click on "Add new template"
[image: Add new template button]

Then on 'check all'
[image: check all button]

After that configure your filters (in the bottom of page) as you wish.

Save, now the filters will display in all categories. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Although I didn't create a new template just edited the old one to include all categories. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

In Prestashop 1.7 the default module to configure is called **Faceted search**.

Comment: This question was about 1.6

Comment: I expected someone wouldsay this. But I reached this page via google when searched for a solution for 1.7 and it might be helpful for someone like me.